# how to change position of button when screen height changes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, autosize

I want to move button when my screen changes, I moved my button successfully but the problem is my button action is same on previous place, it just changed the postion what should I do? here is my code to for btnShr

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 480)
    {
        lbltype.frame=CGRectMake(7, 208, 306, 250);
        imgBckgrund.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 455);
        [btnShr setFrame:CGRectMake(231, 364, 74, 240)];
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show us full code of these button ?

Comment: you mean touch detect at previous place even after u change button frame?

Comment: yes.. when i touch to new postion where i moved that button nothing happnd ..but on privus place it works

Comment: ajay in btnshare there is action sheet   - (IBAction)btnShare:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet * actionSheet= [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Share" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"SMS",@"Facebook",@"Twitter",@"Email",nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:[self.view window]];
}

Comment: Have you add btnShr to self.view after adding all others subviews? I means it should be added at last. I think btnshr is behind of any subview.

Comment: are you doing this conditional code because of iPhone 5 screen size ???

Comment: Can you Edit the Question With code that Moves Button Specifically .

Comment: actually i am adding a subview so i think it is giving problem